# Spark Streaming query dependency

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have a use case where two Spark streaming queries are running and consuming data from the same topic.I want to have a guarantee that Query1 consumes and process the data from the topic before Query2 does.
Is there a way I can achieve this in spark.